# Rewriting html-Image path containing "?" through mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have searched for hours for a tutorial to learn how I can rewrite an image path url containing a "?".

**My images look like this:**

```
<img src="/index.php?rex_resize=600w__/imageName.jpg" >
```

For the sake of caching all images, I must/want to remove this "?" from the string.

**This is the rule I used:**

```
RewriteRule ^rex_resize/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png)$ /index.php?$1/$2.$3 [NC]
```

**This is all the content from my .htaccess with my rewriteRule inside:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^rex_resize/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png)$ /index.php?$1/$2.$3 [NC]

RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml$ index.php?rexseo_func=googlesitemap [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ index.php?rexseo_func=robots [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^redaxo/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^files/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^google(.*).html*
RewriteRule ^((.|\r|\n)+)/? index.php?params=$1 [L,NC]
</IfModule>
```

But since I've never learned proper RewriteRules, I get no match from this RewriteRule, and my knowledge about this is very limited.

For some help I'm thankful :)

Comment: Your HTML code shows the old image URL (without rewrite), show us the new URL, the one you have to route to index.php

Comment: it could also be (with real domain this time: <img src="www.cgnetsphere.ch/files/600w/imageName.jpg">

Comment: By "rerouting" I mean : taking URI "A" (the one in your HTML img tag) and make it become URI "B" internally for Apache.

Comment: What exactly does caching have to do with this …?

Comment: well then my domain is to mutch, and this: /files/600w/imageName.jpg
would be enought to be the new url.
thanks for your patience.

Comment: @CBroe You cannot use a "?" in your url if you want to add Expire Headers for images.

Comment: @pachermann Where does this "question mark VS cache" issue come from ? Parameters are widely used to manage caching on assets for example (eg. script.js?time=<cachebuildtimestamp>).

Comment: @Cbroe well i tested my sites with GTX means the googles and the yslow speedtests. and i found a lot of issues. One is that Apache will not cache any file containing a "?"  in its path . you would probably find this inside the Apache Website Dokumentation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to figure out a pattern to match against in your URL, to know you have to rewrite current request to your image script.

According to your post and commnents, let's say that the pattern is :

All URIs...

- begining with *files/*
- ending with a web image suffix (*gif*, *jpg*, *png*)
- with *something* between those

Write this down into a regexp and your done :

- */* : Begining of URI
- *files/* : our fake directory
- *(.*)* : captures anything (will be stored in $1)
- *\.* : a dot
- *(gif|jpg|jpeg|png)* : file suffix (will be stored in $2)
- *$* : End of URI

RewriteRule :

```
RewriteRule ^/files\/(.*)\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png)$ index.php?rex_resize=$1.$2 [NC,L]
```

### Examples :

Incoming request:

```
/files/600w/imageName.jpg
```

Request after Mod_Rewrite:

```
/index.php?rex_resize=600w/imageName.jpg
```

Note that your example shows a redirection to /index.php (begining with a slash) which should not work when you use a .htaccess file (it only does when having rules in whost config)

Comment: Thank you huge finally i understand now how this matching works. But it seems that There is another Problem with my seo addon, because it still does nothing at all.  Well i will turn off my seo addon to test it propper . and i ill report back what happend.

Comment: hm im wrong when setting a "$" before writing the url?

like: **^/files\/(.*)\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png)$**

and my second question do i not have to write the full part for replacing it: **index.php?rex_resize=600w__/** and then the atoms comming in.

Comment: No, you're right, `$` means "end of the string". It can be omitted but it's worth using it since our uri must stop after an image type suffix. Without it URIs like /files/600w/imageName.jpg_something will be rewrited too. - Edited my answer

Comment: I added an example to the answer to help you understand how to adjust the rule to make it really fit your needs

Comment: Thank your very mutch for your support and patience, im happy that i solved the problem an learned how to use the rewrite rule.
I wish you a nice summer ;) cheers! - pascal